# notify-send not working in i3wm but is working in gmone3

Tags: fedora, gnome3, i3, notify-send

I've been experimenting with i3 on fedora 30 (alongside the default gnome3) and I've run into a problem.

I can get `notify-send` to work in gnome but when I log in to i3 it doesn't do anything.

I've tried Googling but can't find anything relevant.

I can only think that I need to add something to `~/.config/i3/config`

Any pointers would be appreciated :)

[SOLVED] - Thanks to @Theophrastus

Installed `dunst` and added `exec --no-startup-id dunst -config ~/.config/i3/dunst` to `~/.config/i3/config`

Comment: Do you have **notify-osd** installed?

Comment: Thanks @Theophrastus , works just fine.